# How can you place a figure caption inside a table using LyX?

Tags: floats, positioning, captions, lyx

I have 3 graphs I would like to use in a LyX document. In order to save space I have placed the 3 graphs into a 2x2 table and in the final box I have inserted the figure caption.

[image: See Image]

When I try and open the file as a PDF it gives me a whole list of errors.

Is there a way to place the caption in the table (or place the caption over a section of an image) so that I can save some space?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve something similar with a couple of minipages, as outlined below. Please ask if anything is unclear.

1. Add a figure float, and delete the caption that is there by default.
2. Make the contents of the figure centered by changing the paragraph settings within the figure, or adding `\centering` in an ERT.
3. Do *Insert --> Box --> Frameless* twice to add two minipages. 
   Make sure there is no paragraph break between them.
4. For both boxes, right click the title of the minipage box, go into the settings, and change the width to half the line width.
5. In the first minipage, change the paragraph style to centered, and add the two images with a paragraph break between.
6. Repeat for the second minipage, but instead of the second image do Insert --> Caption.

Comment: Just to add on: a "paragraph break" corresponds to a new line in LyX. In other words, a new line will start a new paragraph in LyX.